# playing a wave file with the pi zero

Tags: gpio, audio

I have read several threads, but still no output.

1. First I set: `sudo raspi-gpio set 18 a5`
2. The gpio settings did change per: `gpio readall`
3. `aplay test.wav` produced nothing through the PWM0 (now GPIO18)
4. I ran alsamixer to see if there was a mute on

Not sure of my next step...
Do I need to change the settings on GPIO40 and 45?

Comment: Adafruit have an [absolutely massive tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-basic-audio-ouput-to-raspberry-pi-zero/pi-zero-pwm-audio) on setting the Zero up for stereo PWM. Can you run through the steps in the *Set Audio Output* section on forcing audio to the headphone jack?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I was missing the part about piping the audio to the headphones.  I used:  sudo raspi-config to do that.   So now I hear my wav files on PWM0 and PWM1.

Comment: The next problem is that I need one of the PWM to run some 2812 LEDS.  Can I just route one of the audio channels (HDMI to PWM0-1) and use the other to route DMA generated signals to the LEDS?

Comment: That sounds like it's a whole other question to me - it's a bad idea to try and mix multiple Qs and As under the same headline. Can you post that as a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-basic-audio-ouput-to-raspberry-pi-zero/pi-zero-pwm-audio) linked to in the comments below the question, the solution here was to use `raspi-config` to force the Pi's audio to the 3.5mm jack output:

> - `sudo raspi-config`
> - Select Advanced
> - Select Audio
> - Select Force 3.5mm (Headphone)
> - Select Finish